# Way to know if user clicked Leave on a Javascript onbeforeunload Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I have an AngularJS app. In there I use the following code to let the user confirm if they really want to leave the app:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
    return 'Do you really want to leave?'
});

window.addEventListener('unload', function (e) {
    console.log('unload');
    myRestService.close();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
});
```

The first part works well. The browser displays the message box in which the user has to decide to leave or to stay on the page.

However, if the user wants to leave the page (click the leave button), I have to make a call to a REST backend. For that I thought that I can also register for the unload event that is fired when the user actually leaves the page. However, the event is not fired, or at least I can't see it, when the user navigates to another page or closes the browser.

How can I also catch these events and make sure that my rest call still goes through?

Comment: there are tons of similar questions - you cant

Comment: Don't use those events unless there is unsaved data (it's very annoying to users). Instead save the data, as they are ready.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to make use of angular's "$on"

```
     $scope.$on('destroy', function() {
         someService.hitThatRestAPI();
         // I didn't add a ".then" to the end since they're already off the page
     })
```

Let me know if that works! I'm curious.

I'm assuming you're using angularjs since you have an angularjs tag.